# Transform orientation from vertical to horizontal in recyclerview with animation

Tags: android, animation

I want to make a view like following with animation in which horizontal scrollable recyclerview has to transform to vertical scrollable.

[image: animation]

Please let me know of there is any alternate solution to make this.